# How to implement user input

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just about finished writing this Sub for Excel. I'm basically asking my end user for a total (for example, `$3000`) find the total amount spent by each customer on the list and report those whose total is more than `$3000` (the amount provided by the user) on a new worksheet that I created called `Report`.

I have this code written so far, which also validates the value entered by the user:

```
Sub Userinput()

    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
    Range("E1").Value = myValue
    If (Len(myValue) < 0 Or Not IsNumeric(myValue)) Then
    MsgBox "Input not valid, code aborted.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how I can use the inputted value to search through the customer data base and find more than what was inputted and place that in a new worksheet?

EDIT:
Data sample:

```
Customer orders         

Order Date  Customer ID Amount purchased    
02-Jan-12   190         $580    
02-Jan-12   144         $570    
03-Jan-12   120         $1,911  
03-Jan-12   192         $593    
03-Jan-12   145         $332
```

Comment: Record a macro which does what you describe. Examine the code and adjust it accordingly. If you get stuck somewhere, post the line you're having issue here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know/am able to record a macro, basically been opening up the developers tab and manually been doing it myself thru trial and error(with the help of the Macro button i embedded in my worksheet)

Comment: Could you provide data sample?

Comment: @Vasily, added that in the edit above : )

Comment: A simple search would find examples of how to use the macro recorder. For example, [here is a page from MS](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-2841ba85-9da6-4bd7-93a4-0da90844f283)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub Userinput()
    Dim cl As Range, cl2 As Range, key, myValue
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
    [E1].Value = "Amount Limit: " & myValue
    If (Len(myValue) < 0 Or Not IsNumeric(myValue)) Then
        MsgBox "Input not valid, code aborted.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each cl In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            dic.Add cl.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next cl
    Set cl = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set cl2 = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    [E2] = ""
    For Each key In dic
        If WorksheetFunction.SumIf(cl, key, cl2) > myValue Then
            If [E2] = "" Then
                [E2] = "Customer ID: " & key
            Else
                [E2] = [E2] & ";" & key
            End If
        End If
    Next key
    Set dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

*output*

[image]

**update**

```
Sub Userinput()
    Dim cl As Range, cl2 As Range, key, myValue, i&
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
    With Sheets("Source")
        .[E1].Value = "Amount Limit: " & myValue
        If (Len(myValue) < 0 Or Not IsNumeric(myValue)) Then
            MsgBox "Input not valid, code aborted.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        myValue = CDec(myValue)
        For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
                dic.Add cl.Value, Nothing
            End If
        Next cl
        Set cl = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set cl2 = .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        Sheets("Destination").UsedRange.ClearContents
        Sheets("Destination").[A1] = "Customer ID": i = 2
        For Each key In dic
            If WorksheetFunction.SumIf(cl, key, cl2) > myValue Then
                Sheets("Destination").Cells(i, "A") = key: i = i + 1
            End If
        Next key
    End With
    Set dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

*output*

[image]

Comment: awesome work buddy, First time looking at the "Set" commands so I'm just grasping that. Just one Q: given how the output is pasted in E, how can we take that output and post it to a new worksheet so it looks more organized?

Comment: see updates, replace `"Source"` by the name of the worksheet with data, and `"Destination"` with sheet name for output results

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. I assume you need copied into worksheet in same workbook

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim MyOutputWorksheet As Worksheet

Sub Userinput()
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("WorksheetName")
Set MyOutputWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("OutputWorksheetName")

    Dim myValue As Long
    Dim RowPointer As Long

    myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
    MyWorksheet.Range("E1").Value = myValue

    'conditional checking
    If (Len(myValue) < 0 Or Not IsNumeric(myValue)) Then
        MsgBox "Input not valid, code aborted.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For RowPointer = 2 To MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        If MyWorksheet.Range("C" & RowPointer).Value > MyWorksheet.Range("E1").Value Then
        MyWorksheet.Range(("A" & RowPointer) & ":C" & RowPointer).Copy Destination:=MyOutputWorksheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
        'MyOutputWorksheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Value = MyWorksheet.Rows(RowPointer, 1).EntireRow.Value
        End If
    Next RowPointer


End Sub
```

Comment: OP needs *total is more than $3000*, not each purchasing amount

Comment: I assumed that the Amount purchased  was the total amount spend, if that was not the case, than your answer should be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which takes advantage of straight forward Excel features to `Copy` the customer IDs column, `RemoveDuplicates`, `SUMIF` based on customer, and `Delete` those rows over the minimum.

```
Sub CopyFilterAndCountIf()

    Dim dbl_min As Double
    dbl_min = InputBox("enter minimum search")

    Dim sht_data As Worksheet
    Dim sht_out As Worksheet

    Set sht_data = ActiveSheet
    Set sht_out = Worksheets.Add()

    sht_data.Range("B:B").Copy sht_out.Range("A:A")
    sht_out.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = sht_out.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
            sht_data.Range("B:B"), sht_out.Cells(i, 1), sht_data.Range("C:C")) < dbl_min Then
            sht_out.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't do error checking on the input, but you can add that in.  I am also taking advantage of Excel's willingness to process entire columns instead of dealing with finding ranges. Definitely makes it easier to understand the code.

It should also be mentioned that you can accomplish all of these same features by using a Pivot Table with a filter on the `Sum` and no VBA.